# Expected number of pattern in n coin-tossing without overlapping

Tags: probability, expectation

$N$ is the total number of tossing a fair coin. What is the expected number of occurrence HHH in this $N$ tosses? When overlapping is allowed, e.g., HHHH counts as 2 occurrence, then it is easy to calculate that $$E[X] = \frac{N - 2}{8}$$

What if we don't allow overlapping? e.g., HHHH and HHHHH are both counted as only 1 unoverlapped occurrence, while HHHHHH can count as two unoverlapped occurence. How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: In that case, the probability of such a triple starting at point $k$ will depend on $\lfloor k/3\rfloor$ and whether $k$ is divisible by $3$. I suspect the formula will be a bit messy, but you almost certainly should be able to find a good estimate of $E[X]/N$ for $N$ large.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_k$ be the number of sequences of exactly $k$ sequential heads in the $N$ tosses. For $k<N$, the expected number of these is $$E[X_k]=2\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}+(N-k-1)\frac{1}{2^{k+2}}=\frac{N-k+3}{2^{k+2}}$$ For $N=k$, the value is $E[X_N]=\frac{1}{2^{N}}$.

Then the expected number of non-overlapping triples is $$E[X]=\sum_{k=1}^N \left\lfloor \frac k 3\right\rfloor E[X_k]$$

That's gonna be messy. Let's say, for simplicity, that $N=3M$. Then you can write it as:

$$ME[X_{3M}]+\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} j\left(E[X_{3j}]+E[X_{3j+1}]+E[X_{3j+2}]\right) =\\\frac{M}{2^{3M}}+\sum_{j=1}^{M-1} j\left(\frac{4(N-3j+3)+2(N-3j+2)+(N-3j+1)}{2^{3j+4}}\right)=\\\frac{M}{2^{3M}}+\sum_{j=1}^{M-1}j\frac{21(M-j)+17}{2^{3j+4}}$$

I'd hate to come up with a closed form for that, but it can be done. WolframAlpha gives:

$$E[X]=\frac{5}{49}\left(\frac{1}{2^{3M}}-1\right)+\frac{3}{14} M$$

Which means $$\lim_{M\to\infty} \frac{E[X]}{3M} = \frac{1}{14}$$

When $N$ is divisible by $3$, then, $$E(X)=\frac{N}{14}-\frac{5}{49}+O\left(\frac{1}{2^N}\right)$$ more generally.

It's probably accurate for all $N$, but I haven't worked the other cases out. (It does seem to work for the values of $N$ that I've tried that are quite small, like $N=13$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you mind explaining the first equation E[X_k] in more details? For example, is this X_k an overlapping one? It seems to me that X_k is not allowing overlapping, otherwise E[X_3] should be equal to (N-2) / 8 as I said for the overlapping case, but I don't quite understand how you come up with this E[X_k].

Comment: No, this is the number of sequence of length exactly $k$ long, either starting at the beginning or with a tail before it, or ending the sequence, with a tail before it, or with a tail on either side. So, in the sequence, "HHHTTHHHHTTTTT" you'd count only one occurrence of exactly three heads in a row.

Comment: That's why the multiplier is $\left\lfloor \frac{k}{3}\right\rfloor$. That's how many disjoint `HHH` combinations is contributed by exactly $k$ in a row.

Comment: I think it will be helpful to point out how the first equation is determined. To have exactly $k$ heads in a row, there are two ways. The first way is to have the k heads in the beginning of the sequence ($k$ heads followed by a tail) or the end of the sequence ($k$ heads preceded by a tail) --- these two $k$ heads happens with probability of $1/2^{k+1}$. Then there are $N-k-1$ possible positions of $k$ heads surrounded by two tails in the middle of the sequence, each with probability of $1/2^{k+2}$.

Comment: Your first equation for $N > k$ is technically only valid for $N > k + 1$ right?

Comment: Also, just to clarify if =3 and you have HHHHHH, would $_ = 0$ here or 2? seems like it should be 0 based on your definition of $X_k$.